# Access range of indirectly referenced array in bash

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, reference, queue

I have a bash script that needs to build some sets each containing 1 element from multiple queues (i'm considering using arrays to store these)
For example if i have the following queues:

```
array1=(a b c e f)                                                            
array2=(x y z)                                                                
array3=(1 2 3 4)
```

I need to obtain the following arrays (not necessarily all at once, i process the resulting arrays one at a time)

```
a x 1
b y 2
c z 3
e 4
f
```

The number of arrays is dynamic.

So basically i need to pop the first element from each array and put in another array.
I know i can pop the first element from an array like this:

```
 el1=${array1[0]}
 array1=(${array1[@]:1:$((${#array1[@]}))})
```

Also, i know i can extract a value from an indirectly referenced array like this:

```
val=$(eval echo \${$arr[0]})
```

**My question is: How can i rewrite the part that pops the first element from an array to use indirect references.**

Here is the full test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e 
set -u


array1=(a b c e f)
array2=(x y z)
array3=(1 2 3 4)

finished=false
while ! $finished; do
   finished=true

   array4=()
   for arr in array1 array2 array3; do
      val=$(eval echo \${$arr[0]})
      if [ ! -z $val ]; then
         array4=(${array4[@]} $val)
         $arr=(\${$arr[@]:1:$((\${#$arr[@]}))})
      fi
   done

   l4=${#array4[@]}
   if [ $l4 -gt 0 ]; then
      finished=false

      for i in ${array4[@]}; do
         echo $i
      done
   fi

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array1=(a b c e f )                                                            
array2=(x y z)                                                                
array3=(1 2 3 4)

cnt=0
while : ; do
  line=''
  for a in ${!array*}; do               # loop over names "array*"
    val=$(eval echo \${$a[$cnt]} )
    line="$line ${val:- }"              # build line
  done
  ((cnt++))
  [[ $line =~ ^\ +$ ]] && break         # break if line has only blanks
  echo -e "${line:1}"
done
```

Output:

```
a x 1
b y 2
c z 3
e   4
f
```

Comment: Thanks.I figured out eventually i could use an index instead of trying to pop elements. But, i didn't know about the ${!array*} and ((cnt++)) constructs.